# Variable use outside of Block sentense

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is the question about Block sentence. My question is how to get variable in block sentence out. Please watch my code. The code below doesn't works well.

```
__block NSURL *ssURL
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = 
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    ssURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"screenshot"]];
    [self currentEntry].ogImageURL = ssURL;
    NSLog(@"%@", ssURL); // -> "http://correct.address"   
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

Also I set the variable ogImageURL as below:

```
@property (copy, atomic) NSURL *ogImageURL;
```

Out of completion block, the NSLog shows "(null)" obviously. I want to use the variable outside of block sentence. This is strange.

I have to get the variable from outside of the block because I want to create the table view in which cell calls to get self information to the array.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (indexPath.row < self.itemsArray.count) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        UIImageView *imageViewOgImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
        NSURL *ogImageURL = [[self.itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ssURL];
```

The full source is the 186th line of this: https://github.com/weed/p120711_TechMovie/blob/120723/TechMovie/RSSParser.m

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem of scope, it is a timing issue

in the first example the image view is setup inside the block, which means it only ever happens after the `ssURL` value has been set

in the second example, the block is created but is not called before the image view is setup. The block is asynchronous so is not called immediately: it is run when a response is returned from the operation. If you are setting up the image view based on the JSON request operation it must be done after the result of the operation is set (i.e. inside the completion block)

If you're tableview depends on the result of the operation, then set the value of ssURL and then inside the block, reload the table view

Comment: How can I make completion block with `AFJSONRequestOperation` ? I want to do several things outside of block. I tried `[operation waitUntilFinished]`, but I doesn't go well.

Comment: you are already using a completion block, thats what the success block is

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. I tried to set `NSLog` function **in** and **out** of block. **In** the block, `NSLog` function output correctly. But in **outside** of the block, the same `NSLog` function output `(null)`. I'm sorry to bother you so much but if you have any idea, please tell me.

Comment: correct, its because the block is executed asynchronously, so the order of execution is not what you are expecting

Comment: Thank you for several advices. The order of excution is **1st**: `NSLog` in the block, **2nd**: `NSLog` out of the block. I can see this in console. If the asynchronous operation runs **after** the inside NSLog, I can understand with your former advice. This is strange... Oh.

Comment: why do you need to log immediately? just do everything that depends on the completion of the operation inside the block

Comment: Thanks again, wattson. To tell the truth, in the block, I make a array object which is prepared for other table view. As you know, table view cell calls to get self information on demand. So that I cannot do all of operation in the completion block. I'm going to edit question.

Comment: Maybe this problem is related to `__block` directive ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `AFJSONRequestOperation` `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest` is an asynchronous method, in which case in the second example you'll be setting self.imageView to whatever value is in `self.ssURL` at the time you dispatch the `JSONRequestOperation`.  You'll have to set the image in the successful completion block, as you did in the first example.

Comment: How can I make completion block with `AFJSONRequestOperation` ? I want to do several things outside of block. I tried `[operation waitUntilFinished]`, but I doesn't go well.

Comment: You could call another method.